# Launch instances via Elastic Beanstalk without Elastic IP configured

Tags: elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elastic-ip

I'm creating a tool to deploy Docker images to EC2 via ElasticBeanstalk, so the dev team can quickly demo their work without having to merge. I don't want Elastic IP to be enabled for these apps as they are short lived.

The reason I'm asking this is because if my tool builds more than 5 apps (and it has quite quickly) any new app will fail because no Elastic IP can be assigned to the new app. This is because an AWS account typically has a [max of 5 Elastic IPs available](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_ec2). I can go to the aws web console and choose 'Disassociate Elastic IP Address' (see below) on an instance, after which the ec2 instance will get a new ip (after a few minutes). This is what I want, but I want to do it programmatically, and would prefer to boot the app without it instead of doing it once the instance is created.

[image: disassociate menu option]

Is there a configuration option I can use to use to disable Elastic IP for the new instance?

I'm using the node [aws-sdk](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/), but any tips in any language will do.

I'm creating `m1.small` single instances.

If this isn't possible when launching, I'll have to disassociate the Elastic IP from the instance using the [EC2.disassociateAddress](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#disassociateAddress-property) function.

Comment: If you are launching in a private subnet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086022/setting-up-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-app-without-public-access/39350333

Answer (score 15):

When using the environment type "Single instance", you always get an EIP.

From [Beanstalk developer guide, Environment Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html):

> A single-instance environment contains one Amazon EC2 instance with an Elastic IP address.

Disabling the "Associate Public IP Address" option does not have any effect.

Switch to "Load-balancing, Autoscaling" Environment to get by without an EIP.

Comment: Unlike the other answers here, this actually solved my problem, so thanks :) For future travelers, in the new Environment Creation dialog, you choose the "Load Balancing" option under the "Configure More Options" button at the end of the environment creation form.

Comment: Note: a load-balancer costs at least $16-20 per month (depending on the region) while an EIP is free.

Comment: Starting on February 1, 2024, Elastic IPs will also cost something (even when in use), but it should still be cheaper than a load-balancer.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want Elastic IP to be enabled for these apps as they are short lived.

If you're in a VPC's public subnet (which is likely), one is required for that instance to be able to communicate with the Internet. Per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html:

> To enable an instance in your public subnet to communicate with the Internet, it **must have a public IP address or an Elastic IP address that's associated with a private IP address on your instance**. Your instance is only aware of the private (internal) IP address space defined within the VPC and subnet. The Internet gateway logically provides the one-to-one NAT on behalf of your instance, so that when traffic leaves your VPC subnet and goes to the Internet, the reply address field is set to the public IP address or Elastic IP address of your instance, and not its private IP address. Conversely, traffic that's destined for public IP address or Elastic IP address of your instance has its destination address translated into the instance's private IP address before the traffic is delivered to the VPC.

The automatically-assigned EIPs that come with a new instance don't cost anything, and they automatically go away when the instance is decommissioned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've added more information to the question explaining the issue I'm seeing and how I can get around it via the web console. I may be misunderstanding how AWS is working - but you could advise further I'd be very grateful.

Comment: @ed. I'm not enormously familiar with EB but it looks like from the docs you want to set `aws:ec2:vpc:AssociatePublicIpAddress` in your EB config (and that this is peculiar to single-instance EBs). Alternatively, ask AWS for an increase in your EIP limit - in my experience they'll happily grant it in this sort of situation.

Comment: cheers I'll try that.

Comment: I've tried the flag above to no avail. I think I'm just going to call disassociateAddress via the sdk.

Comment: For the record: `aws:ec2:vpc:AssociatePublicIpAddress` is only for the ec2 instance, if you set it to false then `disassociateAddress` the instance won't have a public IP.

Answer (score 1):

There is an elastic beanstalk environment option that might be what you are after.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elbloadbalancer

Namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
AssociatePublicIpAddress : false

If you set it then all the nodes created by this environment will not have a public IP. Inbound traffic will have to use a load balancer. The VPC and subnets will need to be accociated with a NAT gateway or an internet gateway to get outbound internet access. If you do not have outbound internet access then the Elastic Beanstalk build will fail (It won't be able to reach AWS services).

Comment: I added this to EBS config: 
    `{
        "OptionName": "AssociatePublicIpAddress",
        "ResourceName": "AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration",
        "Namespace": "aws:ec2:vpc",
        "Value": "false"
    },`
Even so, Elastic IP is associating to that instance. Any clue?

Comment: this is not true,  it has no affect on eip

Answer (score 1):

After you Disassociate the Elastic IP Address, you have about 10 seconds to 'release' it. If you release it, it will not come back.

Comment: worked for me! thanks